# Why is the Stereographic Projection not used for Navigation

Tags: stereographic-projections, cartography

The mercators map is most often used to map a rhumb line (path of constant bearing) between two points due to its conformity, however, the stereographic projection is also conformal, so why do we use the mercators over the stereographic for navigation?

Additionally, explaining how to navigate with a stereographic projection with the following example would be helpful. For example, how would I plan my path from point A to point K? Would I draw a straight line between the two, and would that line be a rhumb line?

Edit: the cyan lines are the 85 and 80 degrees parallels, and S is the South Pole (this is a polar projection).

Thanks in advance!
[image: Apologies for the mess, mind only point A and point K]

Comment: Perhaps one reason is that the stereographic projection of the whole globe would send the north pole to infinity so we wouldn't have enough paper to draw the full map.

Comment: @CalvinKhor True, but would it be valid for polar navigation maps? The example is the South Pole of the moon within the 80-90 degrees range, which has near constant scale distortion (close to the South pole).

Comment: For a region that narrow, it does not matter much what projection to use.